# knitr re-use Rcpp function in python code chunk

Tags: python, r, knitr, rcpp

I'd like to know if there's some way to "re-package" a function returned by Rcpp for use in a python code chunk.

In the appended (toy) example I'd like to re-use the "Npi" function.  In other words, I'd like to be able to un-comment the line:

```
## threePi = Npi(3)
```

and have the python code run a repackaged version of the "Npi" returned to R by Rcpp.

Thanks.

-- Mike

````
```{Rcpp defineFn}

#include <Rcpp.h>

// [[Rcpp::plugins(cpp11)]]


// [[Rcpp::export]]
double Npi(const int N) {

  return (double(N)) * 3.14;
}

```{r useFnR}

print("This is from R")

twoPi <- Npi(2L)
print(twoPi)


```

```{python useFnPy, eval=TRUE}

sourceMsg = "This is from Python"
print(sourceMsg)

## threePi = Npi(3)
threePi = 3 * 3.14 # just to let the code render
print(threePi)

```
````

Comment: [This](http://gallery.rcpp.org/articles/rcpp-python/) is probably a good starting point.

Comment: Rcpp is for seamless R and C++ integration.  Python has a different sets of tools.

Comment: Thanks, Dirk.  I'm aware of the purpose of Rcpp.  I just thought Yihui (or others) might have provided some magic to reuse the object provided by Rcpp in a {python ... } code chunk.  Just a fantasy on my part, I guess.  BTW, I've looked at Boost, and Rcpp seems much nicer.